# amplify version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, glibc

There were lot of other questions related to this, however, I'm looking solutions specifically for amplify.

Here is my amplify build logs:

```
2024-01-14T16:14:17.626Z [INFO]: # Cloning repository: git@github.com:anay-208/portfolio.git
2024-01-14T16:14:19.076Z [INFO]: 
2024-01-14T16:14:19.077Z [INFO]: Cloning into 'portfolio'...
2024-01-14T16:14:19.077Z [INFO]: # Switching to commit: 893dd0dc396a332bc2055fe3df3086a8e20ecde9
2024-01-14T16:14:19.090Z [INFO]: Note: switching to '893dd0dc396a332bc2055fe3df3086a8e20ecde9'.
                                 You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
                                 changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
                                 state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
                                 If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
                                 do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
                                 git switch -c <new-branch-name>
                                 Or undo this operation with:
                                 git switch -
                                 Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
                                 HEAD is now at 893dd0d Update email address in Introduction component
2024-01-14T16:14:19.134Z [INFO]: Successfully cleaned up Git credentials
2024-01-14T16:14:19.134Z [INFO]: # Checking for Git submodules at: /codebuild/output/src504315270/src/portfolio/.gitmodules
2024-01-14T16:14:19.141Z [INFO]: # Retrieving environment cache...
2024-01-14T16:14:19.173Z [WARNING]: ! Unable to write cache: {"code":"ERR_BAD_REQUEST","message":"Request failed with status code 404"})}
2024-01-14T16:14:19.173Z [INFO]: ---- Setting Up SSM Secrets ----
2024-01-14T16:14:19.173Z [INFO]: SSM params {"Path":"/amplify/d36nuq8xnduv8k/main/","WithDecryption":true}
2024-01-14T16:14:20.188Z [INFO]: No live updates for this build run
2024-01-14T16:14:20.191Z [INFO]: # Retrieving cache...
2024-01-14T16:14:20.220Z [INFO]: # Retrieved cache
2024-01-14T16:14:46.137Z [INFO]: ## Starting Backend Build
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: nvm install 20
2024-01-14T16:14:47.024Z [INFO]: Downloading and installing node v20.11.0...
2024-01-14T16:14:47.157Z [WARNING]: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v20.11.0/node-v20.11.0-linux-x64.tar.gz...
2024-01-14T16:14:47.275Z [WARNING]: ###############
2024-01-14T16:14:47.277Z [WARNING]: ##########                                                 35.6%
2024-01-14T16:14:47.375Z [WARNING]: ##############################
2024-01-14T16:14:47.376Z [WARNING]: ###########                                 58.2%
2024-01-14T16:14:47.477Z [WARNING]: ##########
2024-01-14T16:14:47.477Z [WARNING]: #############################################                   76.6%
2024-01-14T16:14:47.551Z [WARNING]: ###########################
2024-01-14T16:14:47.552Z [WARNING]: ############################################# 100.0%
2024-01-14T16:14:47.572Z [WARNING]: Computing checksum with sha256sum
2024-01-14T16:14:47.688Z [WARNING]: Checksums matched!
2024-01-14T16:14:48.949Z [INFO]: Now using node v20.11.0 (npm v)
2024-01-14T16:14:48.977Z [INFO]: Installing default global packages from /root/.nvm/default-packages...
                                 npm install -g --quiet yarn@1.22.0
2024-01-14T16:14:48.979Z [WARNING]: node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
                                    node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
2024-01-14T16:14:48.979Z [WARNING]: Failed installing default packages. Please check if your default-packages file or a package in it has problems!
2024-01-14T16:14:48.980Z [INFO]: # Executing command: nvm use 20
2024-01-14T16:14:49.436Z [INFO]: Now using node v20.11.0 (npm v)
2024-01-14T16:14:49.438Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm ci
2024-01-14T16:14:49.438Z [WARNING]: node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
                                    node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
2024-01-14T16:14:49.439Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2024-01-14T16:14:49.439Z [INFO]: Please read more about Amplify Hosting's support for SSR frameworks to find if your build failure is related to an unsupported feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/amplify-ssr-framework-support.html. You may also find this troubleshooting guide useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html
2024-01-14T16:14:49.439Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2024-01-14T16:14:49.439Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2024-01-14T16:14:49.439Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Here is my amplify.yml:

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - nvm install 20
        - nvm use 20
        - npm ci
        - npx amplify pipeline-deploy --branch $AWS_BRANCH --app-id $AWS_APP_ID
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

I believe I got this solution after updating nextjs to latest stable version(^14.0.4)

You can also view the [source code of this project](https://github.com/anay-208/portfolio)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this myself!

It looks like the default for Amplify is Amazon Linux 2. Turns out that's a bit too old for Node 18+.

So, go into your Amplify project -> App Settings -> Build Settings. Scroll down to Build Image Settings. Edit then set the Build Image to Amazon Linux 2023.

Source: [issue in aws amplify Github project where they explain this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3796).

Comment: There is no options for changing build image. Here is a link to screenshot: [https://imgur.com/a/rKbYr7Y](https://imgur.com/a/rKbYr7Y)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using a newer version of the AWS Console, or are enrolled in some A/B testing Amazon is doing, but that's not what I see

https://imgur.com/a/n9DvgcU